# reference - demonstrative determiner

Tags: determiners, reference

I bought a pen and a pencil yesterday. What is surprising is this is
more expensive than that.

In this sentence, I am not sure what "this" and "that" are referring  to.
I first thought that "this" refers to "pencil" and "that" refers to any pen that is distant from the speaker.

How can I infer what 'this' and 'that' represent here? Can the represented element of both be inferred from what precedes, ie "a pen and pencil"?

Comment: You got that right: _this_ and _that_ here refer to _pencil_ and _pen_ respectively. A similar example: _Smoking_ and _drinking_ are both injurious to health: *this* perhaps more than *that*.

Comment: 'The former' and 'the latter' is standard.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Do you mean that those terms (former, latter) are not in the least formal?

Comment: It is ambiguous.  No one should write that way unless they intend it to be confusing.

Comment: @LPH They're formal but that doesn't stop them being standard.  See the Wikipedia attempt to define _Standard English_. Using 'this' and 'that' without obvious context (pointing say) is hardly conversational anyway, and I'd venture non-standard. Usually, at least one of the nouns would be repeated in conversation.

Comment: I think it would depend on context. If you said "Do you want to borrow my pencil? I bought a pen and a pencil yesterday. What is surprising is this is more expensive than that." Here "this" probably refers to the previously-referenced pencil, especially if you're offering it to the person.

Answer (score 1):

It is not the usual way to say that; as far as I know it should not be said that way. In formal writing this would be said as follows.

- I bought a pen and a pencil yesterday. What is surprising is that the latter is more expensive than the former.

In a colloquial context you could say this.

- I bought a pen and a pencil yesterday. What is surprising is that the pencil is more expensive.
- I bought a pen and a pencil yesterday. Surprisingly, the pencil is more expensive.

---

*Addition due to a comment from **[user 405662](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/552671/reference-demonstrative-determiner/552679?noredirect=1#comment1360849_552679)***

It  American English "this" stands for the closest item in the line and that for the other, therefore "this" stands for "pencil" and "that" for "pen" ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/this)). I do not know whether  this is current usage in British English.
For instance, I find  the following in the SOED.

> **3.** **a** In opposition to *that*; the first of two or more things, *esp.* the nearer or more immediate or obvious, the thing actually at hand. **b** [Latinism] The latter *now rare or obsolete* Middle English.

Comment: *the one nearer or more immediately under observation or discussion* 
_this is iron and that is tin_. (Merriam-Webster) Such usage is quite common, in fact.

Comment: @user405662 I do find something like that in Lexico, but it applies physically (Referring to the nearer of two things close to the speaker (the other, if specified, being identified by ‘that’) https://www.lexico.com/definition/this Maybe this is American only. Is it a recent addition to the language?

Comment: Quite. In the OP's example, both *pen* and *pencil* are equally immediate and obvious.

Comment: @AndrewLeach If they are _equally_ immediate and obvious, then the problem stands:  which is to be represented by "*this*"? I do not think that the immediacy bears upon the linguistic context though; I believe that  is in reference only to  the material context. Since "the latter" is assigned to what is most near in the linguistic context and that "this" is not usable any  more, or hardly so (rare), as a synonym, what is immediate to mean in the linguistic context?

Comment: As you have said, you can't represent either by *this* or *that.*

Comment: @AndrewLeach It appears though that you can in American English (Merriam-Webster).